# How to change all elements in a 2D Array to the same value using for loops in java

Tags: java, arrays

This is my first time asking a question here, so forgive me if my formatting is a little sloppy.

I need to know how to set all the elements of a 2D Array to the same value, using for loops, with Java.

I was able to get this far:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class TheArray{
    public static void main (String[] args){

        int[][] pixels = new int[768][1024];

        for(int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++){

            for(int j = 0; j < pixels[i].length; j++){
                Arrays.fill(pixels[i], 867);


            }

        }

    }
}
```

However I have no idea if I have done it right. So all I want it to do is make all of the elements of the 2D array be 867.

Comment: Looks reasonable. What happens when you run it?

Comment: It would run, but since I was using a really basic way to test if it was indeed replacing all of the elements with 867, I was unsure if it was doing what it was supposed to be doing. It's all sorted out now though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use `Arrays.fill` if you're already using `for` loops. Just do:

```
for(int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < pixels[i].length; j++){
       pixels[i][j] = 867;
    }
}
```

[`Arrays.fill`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill(int[],%20int)) would be used **instead of** the inner `for` loop.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot man! I really appreciate it, and this helped me to understand both ways of doing this. (the for loop and the Arrays.fill)

Comment: @GL007 Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following line inside your loop:

```
pixels[i][j] = 867;
```